# how to compare two rich text fields

Tags: lotusscript

I want a script which will compare the content of two richtext field named body in form one and body1 in form2.
I have created two forms whcich contain a richtext type field and created a categerioze view and created a button named compare in this view which will compare the contain of these two fieds and display in a message.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

 Dim session As NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
 Dim doc, doc1 As NotesDocument
 Dim body, body1 As Variant
 Dim view As NotesView
 Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem

 Set session = New NotesSession
 Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
 Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
 Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
 Set doc1=dc.GetNextDocument(doc)

 body = doc.GetItemValue( "body" )
 Msgbox  body( 0 ), ,"Richtext field of First form"

 body1=doc1.GetItemValue("body1")
 Msgbox body1( 0 ) ,, "Rich Text field of Second form"


 'If  body.value=body1.value Then
 Msgbox"both are same"
 'End If
 Msgbox"both are different"

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C

Comment: What language is this? VB? It certainly isn't C

Comment: This seems to be javascript, isn't it?

Comment: no, more likely to be VB

Comment: @Neelam please use `101010` button to format your code. I would retag it as well, but how? The code is VB, and want to know how to do the same in C?

Comment: The code is Lotusscript, which is broadly compatible with VB6

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this manually.
You could use the search-functionality as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787877%28VS.85%29.aspx#re_operations

Search for the entire contents opf box1 in box2. If you get a match, check if this match is the only content of box2. if so, the contents are the same.

Comment: Hi All sorry for the inconvenience i am new to this forum .this is a Lotus Script code.. and I am looking for the same...please let me know if anyone can help.